# How can I optimize this code that does replacement of columns and indexing?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, dataframe, data-cleaning

`census_subdivision_profile_merged` is a dataframe and here I'm doing a lot of things separately. Is there a way I can do them all at once?

```
# Drop missing data
census_subdivision_profile_merged = census_subdivision_profile_merged.dropna()
census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns = [census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns[i]+' '+str(i) for i in range(len(census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns))]
census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns = [census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns[i].replace(" ", "_") for i in range(len(census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns))]
census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns = [census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns[i].replace(",", "_") for i in range(len(census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns))]
census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns = [census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns[i].replace("-", "_") for i in range(len(census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns))]
census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns = [census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns[i].replace("%", "_") for i in range(len(census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns))]
census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns = [census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns[i].replace("$", "_") for i in range(len(census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns))]
```

Comment: Are you only cleaning text in the column header? Could you post a small example dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

You perform 5 times the replace method with a string but you can also use a regex like:

```
import re

#Test data frame
df=pd.DataFrame({"data1":["E %,-$p,e","E    $m$$-%ple"],"data2":["E %,-$p,e","E    $m$$-%ple"]})



#Remove all special characters and whitespaces for each row, for each word
for j in df.columns:
    for strs in range(len(df[j])):
        df.loc[strs,j]=re.sub(r'[-%,$\s]',"_",df.loc[strs,j])


print(df)
```

For your example smth like this should work:

```
for  j in census_subdivision_profile_merged.columns:
    for strs in range(len(census_subdivision_profile_merged[j])):
        census_subdivision_profile_merged.loc[strs, j] = re.sub(r'[-%,$\s]', "_", census_subdivision_profile_merged.loc[strs, j])
```

Alternatively you could try this which removes all special characters as well as whitespaces from the complete DataFrame.

```
census_subdivision_profile_merged = census_subdivision_profile_merged.replace(r"[-%,$\s]","_",regex=True)
```